# External Application Run from C# code is not exiting and not releasing the resource

Tags: c#

I have two applications First one detects the USB/Portable HDD plugging in to the system, and this application then passes the detected Drive letter to another External application and External application ejects it.

The external application is always run as an administrator. It is working properly.

But there is an issue when "Do you want to run this application as admin YES/NO" popup appears, If I select Yes it works properly. Now If I select No even then the USB drive appears to be in use by First application and cannot be ejected manually.

My Code is given below

```
ProcessStartInfo start;
Process exeProcess = null;
try
{
   start = new ProcessStartInfo();
   start.Arguments = @"H:\";
   start.Verb = "runas";
   start.FileName = "Eject.exe";
   start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
   start.CreateNoWindow = false;
   using (exeProcess = Process.Start(start))
   {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The Console output in the catch block shows the message "The operation has been canceled by user" but still the resource is in use. 
Kindly guide me how to tackle this issue.

Comment: Empty `catch` blocks don't help you or anyone else. May not be related to your issue here, but still worth eliminating.

Comment: @Damien_the_Unbeliever I have a console output which says "The operation has been canceled by the user", but still the resource is occupied

Comment: Please don't catch the exception and just print the message. Let the application crash upon exception and use the debugger to examine the exception in more detail. There are a lot more useful information in an exception than just its `Message` property!